# Focal point for/ Focal point on

Tags: grammar, prepositions

Which one is correct?

National focal point for business and human rights or
National focal point on business and human rights

When I googled simillar insitutions these two prepositions seem to vary without a clear rational behind. Are they interchangeable in this context?

Comment: Context! Neither is wrong. It depends on contexts. No wonder you found both prepositions in use.

Comment: Thank you very much!So when I want to refer to the name of institution that provides information and services in the area of business and human rights we can use both?

Comment: Please include the complete sentence in the question to help us help you.

Comment: It is supposed to be a name of institution. National Focal Point for Business and Human Rights in Portugal (for example) or National Focal Point on Business and Human Rights in Portugal

Comment: Neither is correct. A point is a point. A focal point is either a point or a focal point, neither "for" nor "on".

Neither “National focal point for business…” nor “… human rights…” is strictly wrong but equally, neither is in any way useful correct.

Those prepositions might *vary* without a clear rationale behind them and they are not  interchangeable in any context.

Comment: "National Focal Point **for** Business and Human Rights in Portugal" HTH

Comment: Do you have to use "focal point" in the name of this institution? It sounds pompous (to me), and that might not be what you want.

Answer (score 1):

The term [*focal point*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Focus_(optics)) originates in geometrical optics, and refers to the point where parallel rays of light come together at a common point.  The word *[focus](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/focus)* originates in Latin, where it means *hearth* or *fireplace*. It has a lot of meanings, but I suspect that most people think of focusing as something you do with a lens, either directly, or by analogy.

If you start with this optical concept, e.g. with the lens as a magnifying glass or part of a camera, the choice of **on** or **for** really depends on what you are trying to emphasize:

- If your emphasis is on the observation and the instrument doing the observing, then **for** is better.
- If your emphasis is on the thing being observed, then **on** is better.

If in doubt, use *for*.  A  *focal point* requires *something* to be doing the focusing, otherwise the term itself makes no sense.  It's also more in line with the original Latin, i.e. the *hearth* is a focal point *for* the house.